# Tensorflow access to a tensor with a tensorflow index

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor T with shape (A,?,B,C). I also have a tensor index I defined as I=tf.argmax(something). I want to define T(I,?,:,:). The operation T(I,:,:,:) works well when the index I is not a tensor object but an integer. How to do when I is a tensor=tf.argmax?

Comment: Tensorflow arguments are actually chains of commands built up on top of each other, to get the actual value, you need to call the `compute` method (or whatever it's called, its been awhile) to get the actual value.

Comment: I don't find the compute method. I tried this naive way but it does not work:  for m in xrange(...):
        if tf.equal(I,m):
            my_sub_tensor=T(m,?,:,:)

Comment: Tensor flow also has something called a constant or a variable, maybe one of those would fit your use case

Answer (score 0):

Slicing a Tensor, `T(I,:,:,:)` with `I` being a Tensor and an Integer seems to work fine with `Tensorflow version 2.1`.

Mentioned below is the code which uses a Tensor with shape `(A, ?, B, C)` which slices`T(I,:,:,:)` using both Tensor Value of `tf.argmax` and Integer Value of `tf.argmax`.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

b = np.ones(shape = (2,3,3,4))

a = tf.Variable(b, shape = (2,None, 3,4), dtype = tf.int32)

l = [166.32, 10, 26.9, 2.8, 1, 62.3]
b = tf.math.argmax(input = l)
c = tf.keras.backend.eval(b)
print('b = {} and c = {}'.format(b,c))

a = tf.ones(shape = (2,5,3,4))

Arg_Max_Tensor_Val = a[b,:,:,:]
Arg_Max_Int_Val = a[c,:,:,:]

print(Arg_Max_Int_Val)
print(Arg_Max_Tensor_Val)
```

Mentioned below is the Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]], shape=(5, 3, 4), dtype=float32)

tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1.]]], shape=(5, 3, 4), dtype=float32)
```

Please let me know if this code resolves your problem. If it doesn't, please share the code you are using so that we can investigate further. Thanks!

Comment: @Max - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.